# Mongo error, i can't run my two applications

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, angular, mongoose, angular-fullstack

I generated two projects with the AngularJS Full-Stack Generator. The problem is when i run the command *gulp serve* in both projects, only opens one of them. In the console of the other project it show me:

```
(node:1236) DeprecationWarning: `open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0, use `openUri()` instead, or set the `useMongoClient` option if using `connect()` or `createConnection()`. 
See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#use-mongo-client

Error: listen EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:9000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1262:14)
    at listen (net.js:1298:10)
    at net.js:1408:9
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:83:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

I think the problem it has to be ports. But honestly i don't know which file modify or how i need to do it. I know it could be simple, but i'm new in this.

Comment: It's just you two apps are trying to use one and the same port

Comment: the deprecation warning is not critical there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is your Node that is trying to use port 9000 for both applications.

If you want to run both at once, you can either set them to different ports manually, or set the to port 0, and it will randomly assign them a port.

[NodeJS listen port documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/net.html#net_server_listen_port_host_backlog_callback)

Answer (score 0):

So there are two ways to close a node process on a mac. `ctrl + c` or `ctrl + z` and you should cancel out with `ctrl + c` or else you will have a rogue process.

For this I have a function in my `.zshrc`

```
# Find and kill port. i.e. kp 9000
function kp() { lsof -i TCP:$1 | grep LISTEN | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9 }
```

When you change your `.zshrc` or `.bash_profile` remember to run: `source ~/.zshrc` or whatever your file may be.